# phonegap - navigator.connection.type not defined

Tags: android, networking, cordova, navigator

I am trying to check for an established network connection through the phonegap/cordova API, but alas, it is not working.

I added the plugin as explained on the cordova documentation, and `phonegap local plugin list` gives `[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.network-information`.

However, simply calling

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  alert(Object.keys(navigator.connection));
}, false);
```

results on my phone (Android 4.0.4) always returning `0` and running on an emulator with Android 4.4.2 logs into LogCat that `navigator.connection` is undefined. In fact, on both machines `alert(Object.keys(navigator));` never shows the `connection` key.

Any solution?

Phonegap with Cordova 3.3.0

Comment: did you check if the plugin is correctly installed (for examble check that the js file is present in platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\org.apache.cordova.network-information\www) I sometimes had to uninstall-reinstall some plugins

Comment: well, it's not in the directory you specify, but it is certainly at `root/plugins` and `root/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/networkinformation`. reinstalling put it there as well. No fix there.

Comment: in the path you specify, there is a .java file, not js. In the path I specidied you should see (once the project built) Connection.js and network.js if they're not there, your project is corrupt (maybe issues with android.json)

Comment: ugh. Yeah, that seems about right. Any ideas how I can "uncorrupt" it? In particular, you say "once the project is built", do I have to rebuilt the project after I install a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install the plugin it copies files to www/plugins and updates android.json

then when you build the project, the build copies the java to platforms/android/src/... and the js files to platforms\android\assets\www\plugins (and does any customisation defined in plugin.xml)

At multiple occasions I saw android.json not correctly updated and javascript files not copied. Removing and re-installing plugins solved the problem for me.

If you did not perform manual customisations to the platforms/android folder, I think the easiest way to clean your project would be to empty the /plugins folder and the platforms folder and then re-install all the plugins you need.

Comment: sorry I took so long, I accidentally trashed my project and had to rebuild until now. I made it work thanks to you. The documentation of phonegap is really annoying... :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found I had to run "cordova build" and then the status was returned correctly.

**BEWARE**
When I run cordova build, it appears to take everything in my ~/app/www directory and **overried** everything in app/platforms/android/assets/www/

My "install process" is as follows:

```
cordova create app com.app "App"
cd app
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
cordova build
```

I can then do code changes in app/www and when happy, 'deploy' it using 'cordova build' (which seems to always copy the files to app/platforms/android/assets/www/.

If I add another plugin using: (for example)

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

then I need to run

```
cordova build
```

to have it work.

I hope this helps

(I am using cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2 )

Comment: you should not change code in the www folder inside the platforms folder. You should update directly in the root www folder. If you need specific code for some platforms, you can use the merges folder.